# Query in CodeIgniter with several where clauses

Tags: codeigniter, where-clause

I'm trying to make a query with severel where clauses, but it gives wrong results. I need to see these users which have role_id=1 (that are students), which are not deactivated. I take `$this->uri->segment(3)` =teacher_id. And the third where clause is that I need only students that studies in the same school as the school of the teacher , which I take with `$this->uri->segment(3)`. My query is:

```html
public function select_students() {
   

      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('users');
      $this->db->where('deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" || deactivated_at IS NULL 
        AND role_id =1 AND school_id = ("SELECT school_id FROM users WHERE user_id=$this->uri->segment(3)")');
 $result=$this->db->get();
        return $result->result();
  }
```

I found solution:

```html
 public function select_students() {
  
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('(users.deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL) AND users.role_id = 1 ');
        $this->db->where('users.school_id',$this->uri->segment(4) );
        $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better use custom SQL and after that wrap with CI method. This will provide you flexibility to write any custom query as well as protect query with CI security.

```
public function select_students() {
   $sql = SELECT * FROM users WHERE deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR deactivated_at IS NULL AND role_id =1 AND school_id = (SELECT school_id FROM users WHERE user_id= (int) $this->uri->segment(3));
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: I don't know where's the problem - there are wrong results, I your code and I tried many times today. It shows users that have role_id != 1 and which are deactivated. How should I write these where clauses to work in the same time.

Comment: @iveto have you run my code? is it working? if no, what errors are showing. Please give details

Comment: don't know why you are using "deactivated_at" filed as above. it should be a date and `<` or `>` could be used there.

Comment: In my opinion, where clauses don't work. When I run your code, there are users that are not students(with role_id=1) and they are not from this school or they are deactivated. If they must be only users with id=15 and 17, now they are with 5 more.

Comment: I want to see users that are not deactivated. When they are deactivated, they have some date there . When they are active they have this column `deactivated_at` - NULL or in format 00-00-00.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75047/discussion-between-iveto-and-rejoanul-alam).